# Invalid Unicode Escape Sequence with correct syntax (JS)

Tags: javascript, eval, unicode-escapes

I have some code like this:

```
str = ""
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) str += eval("'\\u" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 65536).toString(16) + "'")
```

Occasionally when this is ran in a console, an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence` occurs. The error is in the `eval`uation. The syntax, including the `eval`, should work. A string with a backslash, a "u", and 4 random hex digits is passed into the `eval`. The `eval` interprets the "\u" and the hex digits as an Unicode character. Somehow, the error appears with that good (enough) syntax.
Please find a the reason behind this error, and present a version of this code that circumvents this error.

Comment: How do you know there are 4 hex characters?

Comment: Also, when you do that, it's possible to create non-valid UTF-16 code points.

Comment: Have you tried printing the string before evaluating it, to see what the bad strings are? Also, instead of random, check all values from 0 to 65535. When you see what the invald strings are, you might get some ideas

Comment: @Pointy In the `Math.floor(Math.random() * 65536)` the 65536 is 16 (the number of digits in hex) ^ 4 (hex digits).

Comment: @Vilx- When I tried printing the individual strings given to `eval`, the errors were caused by a missing hex digit in the "Unicode escape sequence". I think a zero in a hex digit had been represented by an empty string by the `.toString(16)`.

Comment: Yes but not all 16-bit values are valid UTF-16 codes.

Comment: Yes, `5.toString(16)` will return `"5"`, not `"0005"`.

Comment: @Vilx- Can you fix this part somehow?

Comment: Well, frankly, I think you should be able to figure this out yourself, but, ok - here you go: `5.toString(16).padStart(4,"0")`

Comment: Shouldn't that be in the answer section?